# How to make a message box appear after a certian amount of time in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

So I'm wondering how to make a message box appear after a certain amount of time because it's for a game I'm making and I really want to know how.

Comment: What starts the "certain amount of time"? Is it when the form loads? When the user clicks a Start button? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

To complete your game ;)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(Sub()
                                      MsgBox("I'm running after 1 sec :) ")
                                  End Sub)
End Sub
```

Comment: Do I put this in
`Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class`

Comment: No. You can put this at the frame that needs that. I don't know may in an action? After a click? Is something are you to know I think!! I've updated the code to give the idea

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: You can see the code (is inside a Sub/Method) then you can use it where it's needed!!

Comment: @coderguy You should explain better what you are trying to accomplish.  Give us an example or a situation.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a [`Stopwatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-5.0) or a [`Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-5.0).

In the `Stopwatch` approach, you can check how long it's been since you started the stopwatch using the `Elapsed` property.

With a Timer, you will get an `Elapsed` event when the `Interval` has elapsed.